# Using jQuery to insert labels into divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this long list of checkboxes with specific labels that look something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='159' value='159' />
<label for='159'>Person 1</label>

<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='160' value='160' />
<label for='160'>Person 2</label>
```

And below this form I have six div's like so:

```
<div id="member1"></div>
<div id="member2"></div>
<div id="member3"></div>
<div id="member4"></div>
<div id="member5"></div>
<div id="member6"></div>
```

I have this JS function so that when I click on a checkbox, it's label is inserted into the first div. Here's what it looks like:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#member1').text($('label[for="'+ id +'"]').text());
        }
        else{
            $('#member1').text('');   
        }
    });
});
```

So one problem is the function currently has to specify which div to put it into (#member1). It's supposed to work that when the first div is "full", the next checkbox will insert its label into the second div, and when that one is full, the third checkbox will insert its label into the third div, etc.

The other issue is if a checkbox becomes unchecked, its label should be removed from its div and the labels in the divs below it should move up. Anyone know if that's possible? I'll accept help for either problem!

Comment: why do you need all those divs to insert labels?

Comment: First, IDs can not start with a number. Second, how do you determine a div is "full"? Third, you should probably put a data-attribute in each div to keep a count of its current labels, and when it hits that magic number, start on the next. If it goes below that, bubble the rest up.

Comment: @j08691: In HTML5, yeah, but [not in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) -- so if using CSS selectors (as you do with jQuery), let's just say it's problematic. A standards-compliant browser will throw on `document.querySelector("#123")`.

Comment: Why can't you append labels into one div?

Comment: I assume you could add up heights of the inserted labels and check that value against height of the parent container. And if height of the container filled up by the labels you can then insert them into next one.

Comment: I think you can just define a data-attribute and have the div number inside of it so you can just grab it with jquery to populate/unpopulate the correct div each time

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I think it is when it is populated so if the div has some kind of content then it is full which is easy to detect

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant populated. That's why I put the word full in inverted commas.

Comment: @Huangism well this is not obvious. He could mean for examples one div has a capatity for 10 labels, and every 10 it should go in the next one.

Comment: @Greg is correct. A div is a container that never gets full, unless you implemented an "endless-loop", that which freezes your computer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant when a div contains one label. Then it is "full" or populated.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj it's not obvious hence 'I think"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat: I would do this completely differently.

But using your current structure: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/axohar) | [source](http://jsbin.com/axohar/edit) (using valid `id`s)

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var $cb = $(this),
            id  = this.id, // No need for `attr`
            member,
            prev;
        if(this.checked){  // No need for `attr`
            $("div[id^=member]").each(function() {
                if (!this.firstChild) {
                    // It's empty, use it
                    $(this).text($('label[for="'+ id +'"]').text()).attr("data-contents", id);
                    return false; // Done
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            member = $('div[data-contents="' + id + '"]');
            if (member[0]) {
                member.empty().removeAttr('data-contents');
                prev = member[0];
                member.nextAll().each(function() {
                   if (!this.firstChild) {
                       return false; // Done
                   }
                   prev.appendChild(this.firstChild);
                   prev = this;
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Minimum changes I would make:

- Put the `#memberX` divs in a container so we don't have to do the `id^=` search.
- Don't use `id` values on the `#memberX` divs at all.
- If you don't *absolutely, positively need them*, don't have empty `#member` divs at all. This would simplify the code markedly.
- If you *do* need them, when clearing, remove the div and just append a new, empty one to the end.

Example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/axohar/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/axohar/2/edit)

HTML:

Just replace the `#membersX` divs with `<div id="members"></div>"`.

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var $cb = $(this),
            id  = this.id; // No need for `attr`

        if(this.checked){  // No need for `attr`
            $("<div>")
                .text($('label[for="'+ id +'"]').text())
                .attr("data-contents", id)
                .appendTo("#members");
        }
        else {
            $('div[data-contents="' + id + '"]').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

You can simplify even more by moving the checkbox *input* the `label`s (which also means you can do away with the `for` attribute): [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/axohar/3) | [source](http://jsbin.com/axohar/3/edit)

HTML:

```
<label><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id="x159" value='159' />
  Person 1</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id="x160" value='160' />
  Person 2</label>
<div id="members"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var id  = this.id; // No need for `attr`

        if(this.checked){  // No need for `attr`
            $("<div>")
                .text($(this.parentNode).text())
                .attr("data-contents", id)
                .appendTo("#members");
        }
        else {
            $('div[data-contents="' + id + '"]').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, your above code works! However if you click a checkbox, then click the same checkbox again, it seems to create a gap? (Regarding whether I need the empty divs. The only reason they're there is because they're styled to look like form fields so the user understands the ideal size of a group is six. It's a design constraint.)

Comment: @AzzyDude: Sorry, I did a dumb thing. Replace `.text('')` with `.empty()`. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it! That did everything I asked!

Comment: Now is there an easy way to limit the amount of checkboxes someone can tick? xD

Comment: @AzzyDude: `if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length > limit) { /* disallow */ }` You'll have to play with it a bit because of the timing of the event, but you'll figure it out. Probably best to check at the end of processing an allowed check, and disable the remaining checkboxes if you're not allowed any more. E.g., proactive.

Comment: +1 for the last part which makes it so much simpler, this.checked and fixing the id to start with alpha

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you have X amount of spots available and you can only fill that many. If that is the case, I think this is what you are looking for: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt5xw/3/). If not, some of the other solutions might be better...

```
var $selections = $('ul.selections');
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var $label = $(this).next('label');
        var $spot = $selections.find('li:not(.full)');
        if($spot.length == 0) {
            alert('no more spots open!');
            return false;
        }
        $spot.eq(0).addClass('full').html($label.clone());
    } else {
        var $label = $selections.find('label[for=' + id + ']');
        $label.closest('li').remove();
        $selections.append($('<li/>').html('&nbsp;'));        
    }
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<p>Options</p>

<ul>
    <li><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='159' value='159' /> <label for='159'>Person 1</label></li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='160' value='160' /> <label for='160'>Person 2</label></li>
    ....
</ul>

<p>Selections</p>

<!-- spots available = as many list items initially in HTML -->

<ul class='selections'>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

I made them lists since that is what they really are, but the code would work the same with DIVs if that is what you want. Since the labels are cloned over, clicking on a label on the selection list will remove it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea. There's X numbers of spots and we can only fill that many. I didn't think of doing it this way.

Comment: However for some reason that code isn't doing for me what it is doing in the fiddle...

Comment: @AzzyDude: Make sure you have my latest edit, if you do, I can't help without seeing your code or some sort of description of the behavior of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MtgPX/)**.

**jQuery**

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div:empty:first').html($(this).next('label').html());
    }
    else {
        var foo = $(this);
        $('div').each(function() {
            if ($(this).html() == foo.next('label').html()) {
                $(this).html($(this).next('div').html());
                $(this).nextAll('div').each(function() {
                    $(this).html($(this).next('div').html());
                });
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way based on your code here http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/rTQMe/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input:checkbox').click(function(){

      var $checked = $('#checked');
      $checked.html('');

      $('input:checkbox').each(function(index){
          if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $checked.append('<div>' + $('label[for="'+ $(this).attr('id') +'"]').text() + '</div>');   
          }
      });      

  });

});
```

Comment: Might be a bit flickery, and doesn't preserve the order in which they were chosen, but still, +1.

Comment: haha - yeh, I know it's not amazing mate ;o) ta. possibly useful for absolute beginner to read tho...

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make this more efficient, but this should work for your purposes:

```
  $(function(){

    var numberOfDivs = 6;

    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if($(this).is(':checked')){

             for(i = 1; i < numberOfDivs - 1; i++)
             {
                 var div = $('#member' + i);

                 if(div.text() !== ''){
                     div.text( ($('label[for="'+ id +'"]').text() );                         
                 }
             }
        }
        else{

             var searchText = $('label[for="'+ id +'"]').text();

             for(i = 1; i < numberOfDivs - 1; i++)
             {
                 var div = $('#member' + i);

                 if(div.text() === searchText){
                     div.text('');                         
                 }
             }

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: The console is saying there's a ) missing after an argument list at the following line:  for(i = 1; i < numberOfDivs - 1; i++) ...?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        if(this.checked){
            var member = $('#member1');
            var i = 1;
            while(member.data('num') == 1)
            {
                member = $('#member'+(++i));
            }
            member.text($('label[for="'+ id +'"]').text()).data('num',1);
        }
        else{
            var removed = false;
            $('div').each(function(){
                $(this).children('label').each(function(){
                    if(!removed && id == $(this).attr('for'))
                    {
                        removed = true;
                        $(this).parent().remove('label[for="'+$(this).attr('for')+'"]');
                    }
                }
                if(removed) //bubble the labels up into the next highest div.
                {
                    if($(this).data('num') == 1)
                    var lastObject = $(this).children('label');
                   $(this).prev().append(lastObject);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```