# Glitch with jQuery function to add label to a div

Tags: jquery

I have to fix a glitch with this code someone wrote but I'm not skilled enough at jQuery to figure it out myself. Maybe someone here can help me. First I'll try explain what is supposed to happen...

Basically the idea is that you have a list of people with checkboxes next to their names. And below them you have six available slots (empty divs). When you check a box, the person's name is inserted into one of the empty divs. Up to a maximum of six obviously.

The tricky part is if you uncheck a box you checked, the name should disappear from the slot, and all the names below it should move up one slot to fill the gap. This is where the glitch is happening. If you uncheck a box twice in a row, the second time nothing happens, or the third, etc...

This is the jQuery function we have so far:

```
$(function(){
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var $cb = $(this),
        id  = this.id, // No need for `attr`
        member,
        prev;
    if(this.checked){  // No need for `attr`
        $("div[id^=member]").each(function() {
            if (!this.firstChild) {
                // It's empty, use it
                $(this).text($('label[for="'+ id +'"]').text()).attr("data-contents", id);
                return false; // Done
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        member = $('div[data-contents="' + id + '"]');
        if (member[0]) {
            member.empty('').removeAttr('data-contents');
            prev = member[0];
            member.nextAll().each(function() {
               if (!this.firstChild) {
                   return false; // Done
               }
               prev.appendChild(this.firstChild);
               prev = this;
            });
        }
    }
});
});
```

Here's an example of one of the checkboxes and some of the divs:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='155' value='155'/>
<label for='155'>John Doe</label>

<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='156' value='156'/>
<label for='156'>John Smith</label>
```

and

```
<div id="member1" class="member"></div>
<div id="member2" class="member"></div>
```

Comment: Do you really need the id="memberN" in the slots div? Because it may be easier to just remove the div entirely and create a new empty one at the bottom (so you get the move up for free)

Comment: How is this different from the same question you asked earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122842/using-jquery-to-insert-labels-into-divs

Comment: @j08691 That question was resolved but this glitch started to occur and I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some strangely un-jQuery-like behavior in your script, but we'll let that go for now.

The problem, as I saw it in my browser's DOM inspector, is that when you unchecked a box it might reassign the contents of the second DIV to the first one, but it wouldn't reassign the `data-contents` attribute at the same time.

Modified code:

```
 prev.appendChild(this.firstChild);
 $(prev).attr('data-contents', $(this).attr('data-contents'));
 $(this).removeAttr('data-contents');
 prev = this;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q6Vg9/

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the problem! And I apologize for the un-jQuery-like behavior of my code :/

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = {};
    $(function () {
        $('[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {

            // index of the checkbox
            var index = $('[type=checkbox]').index(this);

            // modify your names array
            if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') { // add
                names[$('label').eq(index).text()] = 'dummy';
            } else { // remove
                delete names[$('label').eq(index).text()];
            }

            // clear all members
            $('.member').text('');

            // fill all members (if any)
            index = 0;
            for (name in names) {
                $('.member').eq(index++).text(name);
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Basically what the code do is to store all checked names in an array. If a name is unchecked then remove it from the array. Every time all divs are cleared and repopulated with the fresh data.

You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/NanYb/

I realize that my code is completely different than yours but I hope you've got the point.